# How can I write an iterator wrapper that combines groups of sequential values from the underlying iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator

Consider the following sequence:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

I have *input iterators* for that sequence. I want to wrap those iterators on iterators that produce the following sequence instead:

```
(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8), (9,10)
```

If it's not clear, this sequence is a sequence of consecutive pairs of consecutive elements from the original one. While the original has 10 elements this one has 5: each one is obtained from two from the original sequence.

I'm using Boost's `iterator_facade` to implement this, and I have this wrong attempt at this:

```
    template <typename Iterator>
    struct pairing_iterator
    : boost::iterator_facade<
        pairing_iterator<Iterator>,
        std::array<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type, 2>,
        std::input_iterator_category
        // I should probably customize reference too, but it's not relevant
    > {
        pairing_iterator(Iterator it) : it(it) {
            increment(); // A
        }
        pairing_iterator::value_type dereference() const {
            return pair;
        }
        bool equal(pairing_iterator const& that) const {
            return it == that.it; // B
        }
        void increment() {
            pair = { { *it++, *it++ } };
        }
        Iterator it;
        pairing_iterator::value_type pair;
    };
```

One problem I'm facing is on the line marked with A: when the iterator passed in is an end iterator, this will result in incrementing it, which I can't do.

Another is on the line marked with B: I'm keeping the underlying iterator always ahead of the "current" pair, so if the iterator is at the last pair, the underlying iterator will be an end iterator, and thus compare true against an end pairing_iterator.

If the underlying iterator was a *forward iterator*, I could simply read the pair every time on dereferencing, and simply advance twice on increment. But with *input iterators* I can only read once.

Am I reinventing a wheel that already exists somewhere? I didn't find anything like this in Boost, which surprises me a bit. But I'd love to find a ready-made solution.

If this wheel is not out there already, how can I get it to actually roll?

Comment: In my opinion, this is similar to a filtering iterator.  I'd argue that it's best to have the iterator contain the end iterator, to handle the case where the sequence unexpectedly contains an odd number of elements.  This would also solve both of your problems (A and B), because you know if it's an end iterator, and you can separate realization of the proxy pair from incrementing of the underlying iterator.  (I'm not that familiar with Boost's iterator facade, so I'm not entirely sure how one would translate this into Boosteese).

Comment: `Integer dereference()`?

Comment: @David oops, that was an artifact from me 'shopping unnecessary details away from the example :)

Comment: Oh, I lied:  since it's an input iterator, realization and incrementing are tightly coupled.  However, storing both iterators (and possibly an "is at end" flag) would still solve both problems.

Comment: If you create an extra (dummy) element for each array (hidden from the user) then your implementation would work (although it might not be optimal).

Comment: Also, I had a problem _just like this_ a few weeks ago, and _you_ told me the only solution was to use ranges.

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions you already shot down in chat, one with a wierd but relatively safe limitation, and one with an ugly workaround for the limitation:

First idea is very simple, but requires exactly one dereference before each advance

```
template <typename Iterator>
struct pairing_iterator
: boost::iterator_facade<
    pairing_iterator<Iterator>,
    std::array<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type, 2>,
    std::input_iterator_category
    // I should probably customize reference too, but it's not relevant
> {
    pairing_iterator(Iterator it) : it(it) {
    }
    pairing_iterator::value_type dereference() const {
        auto t = *it++;
        return { { std::move(t), *it } };
    }
    bool equal(pairing_iterator const& that) const {
        return it == that.it;
    }
    void increment() {
        ++it;
    }
    Iterator it;
};
```

Second idea removes the exactly one dereference limitation, but is ugly and strange:

```
template <typename Iterator>
struct pairing_iterator
: boost::iterator_facade<
    pairing_iterator<Iterator>,
    std::array<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type, 2>,
    std::input_iterator_category
    // I should probably customize reference too, but it's not relevant
> {
    pairing_iterator(Iterator it) : it(it), dereferenced(false) {
    }
    pairing_iterator::value_type dereference() const {
        if (!dereferenced) {
            auto t = *it++;
            pair = { { std::move(t), *it } };
            dereferenced = true;
        }
        return pair;
    }
    bool equal(pairing_iterator const& that) const {
        return it == that.it;
    }
    void increment() {
        if (!dereferenced)
            dereference();
        dereferenced = false;
        ++it;
    }
    Iterator it;
    pairing_iterator::value_type pair;
    bool dereferenced;
};
```

I probably made several errors, but hopefully this is enough to portray the concepts.

Comment: { { *it++, *it } }; will return the same element for each field (or is undefined) as the ++ does not occur until after the ';'...

Comment: @bytemaster: I'm not sure you're right, but just in case, I fixed it.  It's a trivial change.

Comment: @bytemaster no, the order of evaluation within `{}` is well-defined.

Answer (score -1):

```
template<typename T>
struct piterator {
   typedef std::pair<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type,
                     typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type> value_type;

   piterator(){}
   piterator( const T& t, const T& e):itr(t),eitr(e){
     if( itr != eitr ) head.first = *itr;
     if( itr != eitr )head.second = *(++itr);
   }
   bool operator ==( const piterator& e )const {
      return e.itr == itr && e.eitr== eitr;
   }

   value_type& operator*(){ return head; }
   const value_type& operator*()const { return head; }
   value_type& operator->(){ return head; }
   const value_type& operator->()const { return head; }

   piterator& operator++() {
      if( itr != eitr )head.first = *(++itr);
      if( itr != eitr )head.second = *(++itr);
      return *this;
   }
   piterator& operator++(int) {
      if( itr != eitr )head.first = *(++itr);
      if( itr != eitr )head.second = *(++itr);
      return *this;
   }
   private:
   T itr;
   T eitr;
   value_type head;
};
```

Extra checks would be required to make sure that the pairing iterator didn't 'go past the end' of an odd sized list.

Comment: What does an *end* `piterator` look like? AFAICT, it will simply have undefined behaviour straight from the constructor.